# A week after upgrade whole site is erroring

Tags: drupal

Upgrading to the latest CiviCRM on a drupal based site didn't seem to be an issue.  About a week later, perhaps a change in PHP version, I noticed that my entire site gives this message now and nothing really works: 
Fatal error: Class 'CRM_Extension_System' not found in .../public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/PseudoConstant.php on line 1837

Any ideas as to what I may have done to cause this?  Thank you for all your help!

Regards,
Yasir

Comment: Please specify the versions of CiviCRM and of PHP before and after the updates.

Comment: Did you find the cause of this? I'm having the same problem, something is modifying: 
CRM>Contact>Import>Field.php.suspected
CRM>Contact>Page>Dashboard.php.suspected
Extension > System.php.suspected

Comment: The same problem in our site. Hosting company told us that they don´t run any antivirus/antimalware. It is supposed to be done by 2 separate hacking attacks. Didn´t find any solution to this problem yet, so any help would be very welcome.

Comment: Sounds like an external hack, not to do with the upgrade process. Worrying stuff though. Was this a Drupal or a WordPress site? What versions, and what version of Civi?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and the same solution - the antivirus renamed the

> httpdocs > sites > all > modules > civicrm > CRM > Extension > System.php.suspect

Not sure how to make the server leave that file alone, or what triggered it.

Comment: I had this same issue and was able to fix by renaming. So what exactly renamed this file to begin with?

Comment: You've been hacked. This is caused by a trojan or script injection. There will be several files affected. It will continue to re-infect until you fix permissions on your server files.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your upgrade process did not run smoothly could you check whether the file CRM/Extensions/System.php does exist? If not then it looks like not all source files are on the server.

ps. It is usually a good idea to have test environment where you could test upgrades before actually performing them on production. The same is true for upgrading to the latest php version. First do that in a test environment.

Comment: Thanks Jaap.  The file was there, but it was renamed to System.php.suspected.  Any ideas on how the file could have been renamed?

Comment: Could this be done by any anti virus software?

Comment: I think that's the case Jaap.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would try clear caches first to ensure everything is being picked up from the file system. From the error it looks as though a site move has taken place or the directories have moved/been renamed?

Answer (score 0):

Check it after deleting the temporary folder of civicrm.